# AngularJS. Multiple select JQuery plugin

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, select

What is proper way to implement this bootstrap select plugin (http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) to angular. I have put it in the directive:

```
App.directive('selectmultiple', [function(){
    return function(scope, element, attributes){
        element = $(element[0]);

        element.selectpicker({

        })
    }
})
```

But it's not working. If I write in Chrome console `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({})` - proper combobox appear (opened), but a can't close it. 
Thanks

Comment: if you have jQuery loaded BEFORE angular in page `element` is a jQuery object already so no need to do `$(element[0]);`. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net or plunker that replicates problem

Comment: If the `directive` has a `template` or uses `ng-repeat` to generate the child elements, then it will not be rendered till the next `$digest` loop. In that case, you may have to add a `setTimeout` or `$timeout` with interval `0` and execute `element.selectpicker()` in it to make sure the HTML exists before the `selectpicker` function is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a working example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrianhdezm/TSqvk/). The way I found to use bootstrap-select plugin with angular was:

HTML:

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
     <select ng-model='color' multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-options='c.name for c in colors' select-multiple></select> 
 </div>
 </div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
  .controller('MyCntrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.colors = [
                    {name:'black'},
                    {name:'white'},
                    {name:'red'},
                    {name:'blue'},
                    {name:'yellow'}
                  ];
        $scope.color = $scope.colors[2]; // red

  }]);
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
  .directive('selectMultiple', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attributes){
        element.selectpicker({});

        scope.$watch(function () {
          return element[0].length;
         }, function () {
          element.selectpicker('rebuild');
         });  
          // Watch for any changes from outside the directive and refresh
        scope.$watch(attributes.ngModel, function () {
          element.selectpicker('refresh');
        });
    }
  });
```

I hope it helps you ;)

Comment: provide link to fiddle, please

Comment: It works in fiddle, but I didn't try it in project cause I've already implemented this plugin https://github.com/amitava82/angular-multiselect Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried the solution but my ng-model is not being set.  Do I need to do a ngModel.$render?

Comment: Having the same issue here. ngModel is not being set. Any solutions?